# How to call to Child of a SelectedItem in a TreeView to retrieve data values

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, treeview

In my program I have a `TreeView` that is implemented and managed by a ViewModel/Model.

This is the method that is used to add each node to the Tree, it is located in the `TreeView`'s ViewModel:

```
private TreeModel createNewNode(string value1, string value2, string value3 )
{
    return new BlockingTreeModel()
    {
        DisplayName = "Example Node",
        Children =
        {
            new TreeModel() { DisplayName = "Child 1: " + value1},
            new TreeModel() { DisplayName = "Child 2: " + value2 },
            new TreeModel() { DisplayName = "Child 3: " + value3 }
        }
    };
}
```

I would like to use the `DisplayName` value of each child of the `SelectedItem`. How would I call to that value? For example, setting the contents of a `textBox` equal to one of the child's `DisplayNames`...

Right now I have gotten as far as:

```
TextBox = Tree.SelectedItem.Children //This is where I am guessing that I need to use a method like .Count()
```

Thank you.

**Update 1**

**XAML for the TreeView:**

```
<TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding BlockingTree.BlockTree}" SelectedItemChanged="Tree_SelectedItemChanged" PreviewMouseRightButtonDown="Tree_PreviewMouseRightButtonDown" ... >
```

Comment: How are you trying to display this? Can I see your XAML?

Comment: Well, that string value is going to go into a `textBox`. Do you need to see the XAML for the Tree?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding BlockingTree.BlockTree}" DisplayMemberPath="DisplayName" SelectedItemChanged="Tree_SelectedItemChanged" PreviewMouseRightButtonDown="Tree_PreviewMouseRightButtonDown" x:Name="TreeViewBox" ... >


<TextBox Text="{Binding SelectedItem.DisplayName, ElementName=TreeViewBox}" />
```

Comment: How are you wanting to use the value? You could make a backing field on your view model and bind selected item to that?

Comment: Like I said, I just want to set the contents of a `textBox` equal to it. This has to be done in c#, btw.

Comment: @Ericafterdark Nah it doesn't. I've edited my answer.

Comment: Okay, even if I don't have to do it in c#, how would I do that?

Comment: Why don't you get it from your SelectedItemChanged event handler?

Comment: That's exactly where I am working. I just don't know how to call to each child, in order to get `Displayname`. That line above the first update in my question is what I am trying to do.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40670/discussion-between-eric-after-dark-and-gleng)

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do? Get the display name for each child? Just do Tree.SelectedItem.Children.Select(c => c.DisplayName).ToList(); that will give you all the displaynames of the children.

Comment: Almost! Cool, how do I just call to the first one, for example? I need to call to each one separately.

Comment: @Ericafterdark Tree.SelectedItem.Children[0] to access the first then Tree.SelectedItem.Children[1] to access the second etc.. Let me know if you got it!